# Chef Serverspec should not listen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, serverspec

From this link I could see http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#port

```
describe port(80) do
  it { should be_listening }
end
```

I wanted to test the negative of it.  Say I disabled a port and I don't want anything listening to that port.

What should be the correct test case?

Just starting out with kitchen serverspec test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like:-

```
describe port(80) do
  it { should_not be_listening }
end
```

you can refer in same doc: http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#x509_private_key